# How to sound a beep with PyFace?

Tags: python, enthought, pyface

PyFace is an Enthought library for Python that's supposed to provide toolkit-independent GUI facilities for use with other Enthought libraries.

Can I make it beep? Or do I have to resort to the underlying GUI toolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it will be possible in a future version of PyFace: I contributed a patch.

https://github.com/enthought/pyface/commit/83cef1505e7ab131a51a69e5dcdbd9f53060640e

```
from pyface.api import beep
beep()
```